# Convert DVD disc to USB stick so that it can be played on TV

Tags: usb, dvd, macbook-pro, tv

I have several movies on DVD disc. I have also a macbook pro and a Samsung TV which can read movies in several formats (.mvk, .avi, etc) from an external USB disc. I wonder how could I convert a DVD disc in my macbook (running OSX Lion) to an USB disc so it can be played on my Samsung TV

Comment: Is it a video DVD or a DVD containing individual video files?

Comment: yes, it contains invidiual .vob files. I realized just now that they are playable at tv :-P, so problem solved

Comment: Ah, I see! Would be best to delete the question then, I guess, unless you want it answered (?).

Comment: but I realized later that menus are not interactive, and that it is not easy to select chapter, a better approach then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your DVD is a video DVD**

… you can't "convert" it to a USB drive that will behave like an *authored* DVD, e.g. with chapter marks, viewing angles, animated menus, et cetera. This is a feature of DVDs only. Your TV will only recognize individual media files and play them, one after another, until you reach the end of the current folder.

You might get the option to enable/disable subtitles, but this depends on the capabilities of the TV and the format the videos are stored in.

MKV allows for [chapters to be created in videos](http://savvyadmin.com/adding-chapters-to-videos-using-mkv-containers/), but your TV also needs to support this. Considering that Samsung doesn't offer the best MKV support as of yet, your mileage may vary.

**If your DVD contains video files**

… like MP4, MKV, AVI files, just pull them over to your USB drive and see if the TV reads them.